# UIView centering and resizing with constraints autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, constraints, autolayout

I'm trying to convert my iPhone app to a universal app, but I really cannot figure out the constraints. Tried reading a whole chapter on auto layout but still I cannot manage it.

So there are 2 `UIViews` in my view controller, that are a square. If it's in portrait the squares will show nicely. But when I turn the iPad into landscape the squares get rectangles. Tried really everything.

The problem also, if I manage to keep them in the center and stuff, they should resize to a bit smaller size. Thought this is also possible with auto layout.

**Here is the basic setup for my `UIViews`:**

[image: Basic View]

**EDIT with the new suggestions:**

[image: Try]
[image: New try]

So this is almost perfect, but it should be a square. Any idea's ?

Comment: if show/explain your constrains, it will be better for others to help you

Comment: I'll add some again then. I had deleten them all, because none of them are good, messed up and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the following constraints:

Vertically:

- Top square pinned to superview with inset 10
- Top square pinned to bottom square with inset 10
- bottom square pinned to superview with inset 10

Horizontally:

- Top square pinned to left edge with inset 10 (low priority)
- Top square pinned to right edge with inset 10 (low priority)
- Top square centered in superview
- Left edge of bottom square pinned to left edge of top square

Sizes:

- Top square aspect ratio of 1:1 (ctrl-drag from the view to itself to achieve this)
- Bottom square width and height pinned to top square

This will make your two squares fill as much of the vertical space as possible whilst not overlapping or going outside the view.

Comment: What do you mean with the inset 10? Is that the spacing from the erge? Because in that case, the inset should be more than 10 in my case, because I want it to center on the screen. I've tried it and getting an error. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Tried it today again, and it's no error anymore. But they are not squared to bad.. So almost perfect.

Comment: The insets are there but low priority to make sure it doesn't go over the edge of the screen. Are you seeing any layout warnings in the console?

Comment: Looking at what you have set up and what you are seeing, it looks like those edge constraints are the problem - they need to be low priority, and a low number. Don't worry about hard coding the "proper" number, that's what's causing your problem as it differs from portrait to landscape.

Comment: Hey thanks man, i've figured it out. I've deleted the left and right insets and replaced it with a `Center X Alignment` on my top `UIView`! If you edit your message, i'll accept it as an answer!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that to my answer (it was in the sample project I made!) well done for figuring it out!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding autolayout the basic thing is to visualise how the views varies and find out to what all it needs to be attached,what all needs to be modified on the change in view layout.

- Make sure the fixed values are marked as fixed in the layout
- Make sure all the constraints are set by you.Automatic setting of
  constraint may not work well as expected

You must read this excellent [tutorial by Matthijs Hollemans](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)